# Three finger tap for middle button emulation on XPS13 does not work

Tags: xorg, touchpad, synaptics

even there are tons of tips around my topic out there I still find no solution why creating a xorg.conf file for the middle-button emulation with a three-finger tap does not work on my XPS13 DE 9360.

It DOES NOT WORK for me to make three-finger-taps work as middle-button emulation using an X11-config file (details below).

It DOES however WORK to use the "synclient TapButton3=2". So there seems to be no general problem with the touchpad itself.

I created the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-tap3.conf with this content:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "Mouse Middle Button emulation by tapping 3 fingers"
  Driver "synaptics"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  Option "TapButton3" "2"
EndSection
```

Not surpisingly, a look at the X11-log shows me that the option is read - see very last line of this excerpt:

```
[  6510.852] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad  (/dev/input/event15)
[  6510.852] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
.
.
[  6510.852] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Mouse Middle Button emulation by tapping 3 fingers"
[  6510.852] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[  6510.852] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
.
.
[  6511.005] (**) Option "TapButton3" "2"
```

However, If I log on to the system then, a

```
synclient | grep TapButton3
```

just gives me zero again.

```
TapButton3              = 0
```

Does anyone have an idea, what I'm missing here?
Does the message in the xorg-log only mean the option has been read or does it mean it has been activated?

For the time being, I use synclient off course (automated during login), but I still wonder why the conf-file does not have any effect on my system.

Thanks in advance
Arno